# Query to select only child categories where the category tree/path is in a varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql

If I have a table with the categories tree specified in colum category which is a varchar. The character "-" acts as a category parent-child relationship separator but it is part of a string, like this(simplified for illustration purposes):

```
categoryid    category
----------    --------
    1         Colors
    2         Colors-Red
    3         Colors-Red-Bright
    4         Colors-Red-Medium
    5         Colors-Red-Dark
    6         Colors-Red-Dark-saturated
    7         Colors-Red-Dark-unsaturated
    8         Temperatures     
    9         Temperatures-cold
    10        Temperatures-cold-freezing
    11        Temperatures-cold-mild
    12        Temperatures-hot
    13        Temperatures-hot-burning
    14        Temperatures-hot-burning-1st degree
    15        Temperatures-hot-burning-2nd degree
```

I need a query that would return me ONLY those categories that don't have any existing "child" category. So this query should return only:

```
categoryid    category
----------    --------
    3         Colors-Red-Bright
    4         Colors-Red-Medium
    6         Colors-Red-Dark-saturated
    7         Colors-Red-Dark-unsaturated
    10        Temperatures-cold-freezing
    11        Temperatures-cold-mild
    14        Temperatures-hot-burning-1st degree
    15        Temperatures-hot-burning-2nd degree
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this?
Many thanks!

Comment: This is a fine structure for storing categories, but you might consider a separator such as '~' or `|' that is less likely to be part of the individual names.

Comment: yes, I chose "-" as a separator only for the example. Good point though. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
select c.*
from categories c
where not exists (select 1
                  from categories c2
                  where c2.category like concat(c.category, '-%')
                 );
```

Comment: This is a strange situation, not sure where to write this. Both the different approaches that Gordon Linoff & dasblinkenlight offered return a just slightly different amount of rows. Gordon Linoff -> 2139 rows returned...dasblinkenlight ->2137 rows returned. Why this difference and which one is the most correct one?

Comment: The 2 rows that are returned in Gordon Linoff's query that are not returned in dasblinkenlight's query, are rows that are supposed to be returned :-) No clue why dasblinkenlight's query is not returning them :-S

Comment: The 2 rows in my table that are not returned in dasblinkenlight's query have these values in the "category" column: "Home & Kitchen/Home Décor/Home Fragrance/Incense & Incense Holders/Incense" and "Home & Kitchen/Kitchen & Dining/Dining & Entertaining/Bowls/Soup Bowls/Cream Soup Bowls"

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
select * from test t
where not exists (
  select * from test tt
  where tt.id <> t.id AND left(tt.name,length(t.name))=t.name
)
```

The idea is to chop off all characters of a longer string past the length of the name of this string, and see if the results match.

[Demo.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00986/2)

Comment: Thank you. Please see comment in Gordon Linoff's solution below

Comment: @dodecafonico Gordon's solution uses a different (and very clever) strategy for rejecting the same entry as its own substring. It's strange that the queries return different results. Can you post two rows by which the results are different?

Comment: thanks. I posted the differing rows in Gordon's comments

Comment: @dodecafonico Interesting. The two lines don't look special at all. Are you sure that there are no duplicates in your table? I.e. `select count(distinct name) from ...` and `select count(name) from ...` produce the same number?

Comment: @dodecafonico Another possibility is that there are categories with the two differences as their prefixes, e.g. `'Home & Kitchen/Home Décor/Home Fragrance/Incense & Incense Holders/Incenses'` with an `'s'` at the end. If that is the case, my query would throw out the one with no `'s'` at the end, while Gordon's would keep it.

Comment: that's it... it's the last possibility :-) I have 2 other categories that are: "Home & Kitchen/Home Décor/Home Fragrance/Incense & Incense Holders/Incense Holders" and "Home & Kitchen/Kitchen & Dining/Dining & Entertaining/Bowls/Soup Bowls/Cream Soup Bowls & Saucers". Many thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

This will work. Try it out once.

```
SELECT categoryid
     , category
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE category like '%-%-%'
```

Comment: Thanks, but this query returns also many categories that have child categories further deep. In my real table I have as much as 8 deep childs!

Comment: Add one more condition in where clause of above query to restrict data.
WHERE clause will look like:
WHERE category like '%-%-%' AND category NOT LIKE '%-%-%-%'

Comment: nope. adding that extra condition removes most of the rows that I need returned

Comment: Can you be specific which type of rows are getting excluded?

Comment: I would guess that with your second NOT LIKE clause all the rows that have 3 separators are excluded. Many of these are childs themselves, so I need them returned.

Comment: Actually, your query is returning me ONLY those rows that have 2 separators. It doesn't return me anything further deep. Thanks anyway :-)

Comment: How much further deep you need to return your data? If you need to return data with 2 or more levels than my first query will do that. If you have a defined no of levels for which you need to return your data. You can update the NOT LIKE condition accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for insisting but I want the query to work for any level of depth. The current maximum depth is 8 but it might increase in the future without me knowing. Gordon Linoff has already posted a solution that perfectly works for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may need to use this

```
select categoryid, category from table
where length(category)-length(replace(category,'-',''))>=2
```

Comment: This one doesn't work properly for my problem because it still returns some of the categories that do have childs further deep. But thanks anyway :-)